# Watir-ruby how to click on text by color property

Tags: css, ruby, watir

I'm trying to click on an element in a table. There are a few elements with the same class `<span class="price">`, and I need to click on one with a specific color property: `color:#555`.
I tried a couple of approaches that didn't work:

```
1- browser.span(:class => 'price', visible: true ).click  -- not work  
2- browser.span(:class => 'price', ).style(color: '#555').click  -- undefined method click for string
```

The link depends on product availability so some times is grey and I can't click on it.  Is there any way apart from this one to achieve this click?

Comment: It would help if you share the relevant HTML that you are working trying to interact with. For example, it's not clear if the color is applied by a style attribute or a class attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
browser.span(:css, 'span[style="color: #555;"].price').click
```

You'll have to use the css selector, as the style method can only be used to return values in the style attribute. Example of that:

```
browser.spans(:class, 'price').each {|e| puts e.style('color')}
```

As a side note, if you have any control over the source I would consider making product availability more explicit in the CSS.